# Unable to display images in browser using python

Tags: python, html

I'm trying to create a simple web browser.
I have an index.html file placed in my local. I'm trying to start a client server connection and then display the html file in the browser.

I'm able to open the index.html file and read it's contents except some of it's contents. There are links which point to the images in the local directory, but when clicked on it in browser, it's not opening.

Here is the sample code.

```
    HOST, PORT = '', 8888

listen_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
listen_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
listen_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
listen_socket.listen(1)

listen_socket.listen(1)
print('Serving HTTP on port %s ...' % PORT)
os.chdir("some directory where index.html is present")
open_file=open('index.html','r')
print(os.getcwd())
#http_response=open_file.read()

""" sample html code where image exists
<image src="./images/welcome.png" height=180px />
The index.html is perfectly fine, but i'm not able to display the images
in browser"""


while True:
    client_connection, client_address = listen_socket.accept()
    request = client_connection.recv(1024)
    print(request.decode('utf-8'))

    http_response = open_file.read()



    client_connection.sendall((str.encode(http_response)))
    client_connection.close()
```

Is there some kind of special encoding that needs to be done for displaying images?

Please note that I can't use any external modules.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here with running a socket and listening the same? You are accessing this html via browser?

Comment: yes i'm accessing it via browser

Comment: Did you try using absolute path for images?

Comment: Yeah even i did that, i tried placing an image file and then using the absolute path but still i get an error saying no data received while opening the html

Comment: How are you telling the browser to treat this file as html by sending it? Shouldn't you also send, `client_connection.send('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: text/html\n\n')` before `client_connection.sendall((str.encode(http_response)))` ?

Comment: oh ok ok sorry I didn't think of that, new to python and socket programming.

Answer (score 0):

For the content to be treated as a valid html file, one needs to send the required content's which are treated as some kind of rule set to the decoder like browser to realize that it should treat it has a **protocol** of **HTTP/1.1** and also the **Content Type** is of type **html** and so add:

`client_connection.send('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: text/html\n\n')`

before

`client_connection.sendall(http_response.encode('UTF-8'))`

Comment: hi Monk, is there any encoding that I need to change here? cos I'm getting the following error. "TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface"

Comment: Which version of python are you using?

Comment: I'm using python v3.4

Comment: Can you try the last line as `client_connection.sendall(http_response.encode('UTF-8'))`. Python 3.x string is not same as python 2.x. Either convert to bytes or try the above. I currently am not having anything to test that syntax.

Comment: Just updated the answer to reflect the python 3 version